# Can you play in Minecraft Xbox one with a Xbox 360 Controller?

Tags: controllers, xbox-one, minecraft-legacy-console

Me and my friend want to have a split screen thing in Minecraft but he has  a Xbox 360 controller and we are playing in Xbox one. Can you play in Minecraft Xbox One with a Xbox 360 controller?

Comment: If someone accepts my edit add `controllers` tag please.

Answer (score 5):

As per [Xbox.com](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/console/compatibility-with-xbox-360-faq#Xbox%20360accessorycompatibility2):

> **Q:** Can I use my Xbox 360 wired/wireless controller, accessories (racing
>   wheel, wireless headset, etc.), or power supply with Xbox One (or vice
>   versa)?
>
> **A:** No. Controllers and accessories that work with Xbox 360 won't work
>   with Xbox One (and vice versa). Also, the power supply from the Xbox
>   360 does not connect to the Xbox One console, and it will not satisfy
>   the new console's power requirements.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a PC you can stream the game via the Xbox app.  You can use a 360 controller to play streamed games.  Note, you will need to use a wired 360 controller or use a wireless adaptor for the PC to recognise the controller.

Answer (score 1):

No, because they're in different platforms. A 360 controller won't work for an Xbox One.

Comment: "No, because they're different plataforms" isn't a good reason. You can buy a PS1, PS2, PS3 and PC compatible controller and it will work on all 3 consoles. One example is the [Lifetech Gampead AngEvil](http://www.lifetech-world.com/productdetail.cjp.htm?id=107) (Sorry, there's no English version)

Comment: Note: Xbone is short for Xbox One.